# SQL confusion with the groupby function

Tags: sql

```
SELECT  customers.CompanyName,
    customers.ContactName,
    customers.phone,
    customers.country,
    SUM(orders.Freight) AS Total_Freight
FROM    CUSTOMERS INNER JOIN ORDERS
ON   customers.CustomerID = ORDERS.customerID 
WHERE orders.orderDate BETWEEN '1993-07-01' AND '1993-08-31' 
GROUP BY Orders.orderID, customers.CustomerID
ORDER BY customers.companyName
```

Above is my code, but I am getting error 
Column 'CUSTOMERS.CompanyName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Why is that? Where did I go wrong?

[The database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGI6u.png)

THis is the question.

2. List the company name, contact name, phone number, and country from the Customers table, and the sum of the freight from the Orders table where the order date is between July 1, 1993 and August 31, 1993. Order the result set by the company name. The query should produce the result set listed below.

   The result format is too messy, I doubt it will be helpful to anyone.

Comment: What part of the error do you not understand?  It seems really lear to me.

Comment: Sorry. I don't understand how to fix it because I don't really understand the group by well.

Comment: I received the same error :( "GROUP BY Orders.orderID, customers.CustomerID, customers.CompanyName"

Comment: Please indicate which database you are using, but whichever it is, it seems to be treating `customers` and `CUSTOMERS` as two different tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use all the selection column in group by also as you used aggregate function

```
 SELECT  customers.CompanyName,
        customers.ContactName,
        customers.phone,
        customers.country,
        SUM(orders.Freight) AS Total_Freight
    FROM    CUSTOMERS INNER JOIN ORDERS
    ON   customers.CustomerID = ORDERS.customerID 
    WHERE orders.orderDate BETWEEN '1993-07-01' AND '1993-08-31' 
    GROUP BY customers.CompanyName,
        customers.ContactName,
        customers.phone,
        customers.country
    ORDER BY customers.companyName
```